# When i create sitemap.xml file dynamically in react app i face this type of issue mention below

Tags: reactjs, sitemap.xml

The sitemap-generator.js file :

```
require("babel-register")({
    presets: ["es2015", "react"]
});
const router = require("../src/App").default;
const Sitemap = require("react-router-sitemap").default;

function generateSitemap() {
    return (
        new Sitemap(router)
        .build("http://localhost:3000/")
        .save("../public/sitemap.xml")
    );
}

generateSitemap();
```

The package.json file :

```
  "scripts": {
    "sitemap": "babel-node ./src/sitemap-generator.js",
    "predeploy": "npm run sitemap"
  },
```

The issue which i am facing right now :

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\prince\Desktop\new-sharepoint-empower-dynamic-content-react-site\src\sitemap-generator.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I wish that one of you will give me the perfect solution of my issue .
Thank You.